# Moqing MVVM Light's IMessenger

Tags: moq, mvvm-light

While trying to write some unit tests with **Moq** and **MVVM Light**'s messenger class I've encountered an issue.  The issue is how can you `Mock<IMessenger>();` and verify that a message was received and the action processed?

What is the correct way write the test if using `IMessenger`?  I've seen plenty of examples using Messenger.Default, 
and having `Messenger.Reset()` in the `TestInitialize` method.  I used `IMessenger` believing it would help with test-ability.

Using Moq to verify that a message is sent works as I would expect.

```
[TestMethod] 
public void LoadData_SendsUpdateStatusEvents()
    {
        //Arrange
        _mockMessenger.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<string>(), 
                             It.IsAny<UpdateStatusEvent>()));
        //Act
        //Assert
        _mockMessenger.Verify(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<string>(), 
                              It.IsAny<UpdateStatusEvent>()), Times.Exactly(2));
    }
```

However, if I have this registration in my constructor..

```
 _messenger.Register<IUnitsManager>(this, OnUpdatedUnitsEvent);
```

And I write a unit test to check that OnUpdatedUnitsEvent runs...

```
[TestMethod]
public void OnUpdatedUnitsEvent_UpdateUserUnitValueOfAllMaterials()
{
    //Arrange
    _mockUnits.Object.SetUnitsToMetric();
    _mockMessenger.Object.Send(_mockUnits.Object);

    //Act
    var currentItem = _materialMasterVm.MaterialModels.CurrentItem as MaterialDetailViewModel;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(DensitySolidSymbols.KgCm3, currentItem.Density.UserUnitType);
    Assert.AreEqual(PressureSymbols.KPa, currentItem.YieldStress);
    Assert.AreEqual(PressureSymbols.KPa, currentItem.YoungsModulus);
}
```

What is the recommended approach to get this to work using when using IMessenger and Moq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
// This is a field in your test fixture
Action<IUnitsManager> _callback;

...

// In your test setup, save the delegate that is registered with the message type
mockMessenger.Setup(x => x.Register(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<Action<IUnitsManager>>()))
             .Callback<object, Action<IUnitsManager>>((o, a) => _callback = a);

...

// When you want to send the message, invoke the callback
_callback(_mockUnits.Object);
```

However, I want to add that when sending messages in tests using the `IMessenger`, I do *not* mock it.  The above is a little too much hassle to setup, and besides, this is exactly what the `Messenger` concrete does anyways.  To put it another way, I'm either putting my faith in Moq's `Setup`/`Callback` mechanism or in the MVVM Light `Messenger`'s `Register`/`Send` mechanism.  I choose the latter because I don't need to do any extra setup in my tests to make it work.

So, when I need to test that my SUT registers for and handles messages properly, I assume the `IMessenger` works as expected and just use a concrete instance, i.e.:

```
// Create a new messenger every test
IMessenger mockMessenger = new Messenger();
// Send the message
mockMessenger.Send<IUnitsManager>(_mockUnits.Object);
```